# How do I get non-ascii form data when using enctype multipart/form-data

Tags: html, file-upload, multipartform-data, enctype

I have a HTML form that uses POST with an enctype of multipart/form-data. I would like for the user to both be able to upload a file and enter in some additional information (in the same HTML form).

Currently the input values only come back correctly when the input fields are regular ascii characters. I need to be able to handle input that is in non-ascii format too. How do I force the values of the input fields to be UTF-8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: The simplest solution is to use UTF-8 everywhere. Injecting UTF-8 data in an application that uses ASCII ranges from cumbersome to just not possible (depending on the specs).

Comment: `How do I force the values of the input fields to be UTF-8?` by declaring the page UTF-8 using the `content-type` header - that should be enough

Comment: @Pekka웃 - That's enough if (and only if) the complete application (including HTML and database) is already using UTF-8.

Comment: @Álvaro well, not necessarily... He could accept UTF-8 data and store it in a latin1 table, auto-converting it at the time of insertion by declaring the connection properly (not that it would make any sense, of course) Anyway, he should be doing it the way you say, of course.